# Whats the difference between WebRTC and libp2p?

Tags: networking, ssh, webrtc, p2p, libp2p

I'm trying to build a p2p terminal sharing utility where PCs behind a NAT can share their terminals to other PCs behind a NAT through the public internet. (both PCs are on different private network basically). Another requirement is to provide a web based terminal as well ( and hence webrtc seems useful ) .Came across two promising solutions - webrtc and libp2p. But what is the fundamental difference between the two?

PS: `ssh` Tag might be misleading here. But on a broad level, all I'm trying to do is a make-believe SSH into a system that does not have a public IP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **WebRTC** is a low-level Browser API for P2P communication between browsers. See [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) or [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) for high-level introduction and history.
- **libp2p** is a library written in JS, NodeJS, Go, Rust (with more in the way) that implements Peer to Peer communication based on [IPFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System). From what I see it uses WebRTC and WebSockets in Browser.

Comment: There are modules for libp2p which uses WebRTC, but it also/usually works without. It's also worth to mention **IPFS** in the context of libp2p. From the libp2p GitHub README: _libp2p grew out of IPFS_, [...]. _Some knowledge of IPFS/libp2p may be required, as well as the infrastructure behind it_ - [...]

Comment: @timaschew added info about IPFS to the answer, I've didn't mention this because I've thought that it's not important in the case of WebRTC.